# How to always return Graphql field?

Tags: graphql

I would like to always return a field when certain requests are made so that additional actions can be performed by the client.

For example if user registration has been successful I want to show flash message. But it has to be handled by the backend and not the front end.

I could "require" clients to always request specific field that would hold the needed information but it could be easily overlooked so I'd like to return data whenever needed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not enough information supplied. Are you using ajax (your registration form submits via ajax)? Or are you talking about a decoupled front end? Have you got graphql working? Are you using a module for the graphql? What version of Drupal? If you want help, you must make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the GraphQL spec that allows particular fields to be required in the same sense that arguments can be required. This can be handled inside the resolver, however. For example, if you have a query called `getFoos`, and you want to require the clients to always request the field `foo` when fetching that query, your resolver for `getFoos` could look like this:

```
function (obj, args, ctx, info) {
  const fields = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections.filter(s => s.name.value)
  if (!fields.includes('foo')) return Promise.reject(new Error('Missing field foo!'))
  // continue resolving the query as normal
}
```

Each resolver takes as its fourth parameter an info object that contains detailed information about the request, including what fields were requested. So inside your resolver, just verify that the field was included, and if it's missing, return a rejected Promise instead. This will cause your query to fail anytime that particular field is missing.